# Showing that a number is part of sequence A000275 in OEIS

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

Consider the sequence of integers defined recursively by $c_0 = 1$ and
$$
c_p = \sum_{l = 0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p+l+1} \binom{p}{l}^2 c_l
$$
for $p \geq 1$. This is sequence [A000275](http://oeis.org/A000275) in the online encyclopedia of integer sequences and its first few members are 1, 1, 3, 19, 211, 3651.

I believe this sequence comes up in a problem I'm dealing with (calculating the norm of a $(p,p)$-form on an $n$-dimensional complex vector space) but I can't quite prove that the numbers I have are the $c_p$. I've got it down to showing that if a number $A_{n,p}$ (for $n$ and $p$ such that $2p \leq n$) satisfies
$$
\binom{n}{p} \Biggl(
A_{n,p} + \sum_{l=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p+l} c_l \binom{p}{l}^2 \cdot \frac{\binom{n-p+l}{p-l}}{\binom{n}{p-l}}
\Biggr) = 1
$$
then $A_{n,p} = c_p$ (unless I've made a mistake somewhere). But here I'm stuck. I'm awful with all things involving finite sums and binomial coefficients, can someone help here?

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I was able to figure this out. The details are here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4048
It wasn't that exciting: treat the expression like a polynomial in $n$, proceed by induction and compare top-degree coefficients.